# OAuth - implementing a "userInfo" page. Where's the spec?

Tags: oauth

Many of OAuth providers host "userInfo" pages which are used by clients to fetch display names and identifiers etc.  This endpoint is hit after code generation and exchange for a token. Spring boot requires this endpoint when configuring an OAuth client. For example

- Google:  https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo
- Facebook: https://graph.facebook.com/me

I want to implement this for our own OAuth provider.  Implementing it is not a problem, but I need to define what I'm implementing. I've looked all over and read a ton of specs but cannot find where this behaviour is described.

Does anyone know what specification this is part of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google conforms to OpenID Connect: http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#UserInfo Facebook doesn't conform to any open specification, they're doing their own thing; it just happens to look similar.

Comment: Thanks Hans.  Do you know if other biggies like github, stackoverflow or slack do things the OpenID connect way?

Comment: Microsoft has adopted OpenID Connect. Slack and Github chose to build their own. Stackoverflow is stuck on the deprecated OpenID 2.0.